# When I click a facebook share button, I should share multiple links with multiple images as one post on facebook timeline

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Is there a possibility of sharing on facebook timeline, multiple links with multiple images which are nicely formatted as one post at the click of a share button?

The idea is that, I currently maintain an e-commerce site and I want any customer to be able to share all the products in an order unto their timeline as a single post with links back to the site.

Currently, using the facebook open-graph api I can only share a link and an image on the click of a facebook share which means I would need to have seperate share button for each products but from the user experience perspective this would not be efficient as it would be better to only have one button to carry out the post and all the products in the order are all shared as one post on the customer facebook timeline.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately it's not possible. The whole idea behind open graph is interacting with objects one by one. You can combine whole list of products into one object and share it, but it will still have only one link and image representing that object.